# I want to generate random numbers till 3 but i don't want to repeat them. How can i make it work?

Tags: javascript

```
function generator(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var arrays = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
        if (arrays.length = 0){
            console.log(random);
            arrays.push(random);
        } else if (random = arrays[i]){
            generator();
        } else {
            console.log(random);
            arrays.push(random);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to push numbers to array then check them with for loop but it didn't work.
I basically want to know why this code doesn't work. Is it wrong to use for loop here?

Comment: You are using `=` in your if-statements. Note that a single `=` means assignment. Use `==` or `===` for comparing things.

Comment: You have `var arrays = [];` before for loop and in the loop you have `i < arrays.length`, Does that make any sense?

Comment: Can use `indexOf` instead of a loop. Also note that your loop/recursion will not end if all three numbers are part of the list. Furthermore you keep increasing the calls on `generator()` in each sub loop since you have no `break`.

Comment: Don't use recursion for this simple task. Also, use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test if the newly-generated random number is already in the array.

Comment: I wanted to push new number so every time u call that function it generates new random number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.

```
    var arrays = [];
function generator(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (arrays.length == 3){
        stop();
    } else if (arrays.indexOf(random) == -1){
        console.log(random);
        arrays.push(random);
    } else{
        generator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
let num, already = new Object;

    let start = 0, end = 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3;)
    {
        num = (Math.random() * (end - start) + start) ^ 0;
        if (!(num in already))
        {
            already[num] = num;
            i++;
            document.write(String(num));
            if (i < 3)
                document.write(', ');
        }
    }
```